# Email synchronization only on business days in Windows Phone 8

Tags: sync, email, exchange

Is there a way to synchronize Email/Exchange accounts only on defined days on defined times? I have a Exchange account from work and I want to receive those messages only on business days between 8:00 and 16:00.

I know that this is possible on android and on Symbian but don't seem to find and setting for it in Windows Phone 8 (Lumia 920)

Comment: Not sure, can't this be done using domain policies? IIRC you can deny logon outside business hours. No logon, no exchange, no mails. Simple calculation, but just an idea as I'm not an IT support guy (meant with total respect).

Comment: I work in a large company and IT support will not change domain policies because I don't want to get work mail. I think this should be done in a email client, not on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible on WP8 device itself. Sorry.
You can always add this to the feature request for WP.

I've got a list of Microsoft feedback routes at http://dfwiki.devfish.net/technology.Microsoft-feedback-routes.ashx .  There's a number of Windows Phone options.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this has already been requested at [uservoice](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1732491-ability-to-set-a-schedule-of-when-to-check-e-mails)

Comment: Make sure you vote it up.